# When did this global rules change happen in Mathematica? Is this change documented?

Tags: replacement, core-language, compatibility, term-rewriting

In this [Wolfram talk video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FWzvXPLw7A)  titled "Professor Richard J. Gaylord's Wolfram Language Fundamentals Part Two"  he shows at time 36:45 the following

[image]

Where there are two definitions for `w` one after that other, then he says that both are entered in the global rules database and then when one is called, the first is called as you see from the screen shot above.

I thought this was strange, because when I tried it on V 13.1, only one definition was entered into the global rules database:

[image]
[image]

The video is from 2014. So look like it was around version 10 of Mathematica.

My question is: When did this change happen? And is it documented?  Notice that different result is obtained than what shows in the video.

code

```
ClearAll[w,x]
w[x_]:=x^4
w[_]:=RandomReal[]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With *Mathematica* 5.2 I reproduce the behavior from the talk:

[image: screenshot]

But with version 6.0 we do not:

[image: screenshot2]

So the change happened in 6.0.

Comment: Is this desired behavior?

Comment: @QuantumDot I think so. The previous behavior looks like a bug.

Comment: @QuantumDot - there is no expression that would not match `x_` but does match `_`.  So in the original output from the image in the OP, there are two definitions given for `?w` but the second would **never** come into play.  To me it seems like a good change, a bug fix really. (edit: my browser says alexey beat me to this by 20 seconds)

Comment: I take the liberty to add the testing result, feel free to rollback if you don't like it :) .

Comment: @xzczd Thank you. :)

Comment: Ok, I agree.  The recent behavior is desired. For reasons I cannot explain, I assumed (incorrectly) that x_ would match to the special case of 2…. Don’t even know how/why my brained picked the number 2, don’t ask.

Comment: If you did want to have both definitions for whatever reason, you could assign them this way: `DownValues[w] = {HoldPattern[w[x_]] :> x^4, HoldPattern[w[_]] :> RandomReal[]};`